# Fullcalendar V4: How to parse json received from ajax into event list

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to retrieve a list of events from an ajax call. I use the following code.

```html
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
 { var calendarEl = document.getElementById("id_d_agenda_1");
   var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
     plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
     header: {
       left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
       right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
     },
     defaultDate: '2019-08-12',
     editable: true,
     navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
     eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
           selectMirror: true,
     select: function(arg) {
       var title = prompt('Event Title:');
       if (title) {
         calendar.addEvent({
           title: title,
            start: arg.start,
                end: arg.end,
                allDay: arg.allDay
               })
             }
            calendar.unselect()
           },
     events: function(arg) {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'd.php',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {
              cmd:'getdata',
              start:arg.startStr,
              end:arg.endStr,
              tz:arg.timeZone,
              component:'d_agenda_1',
           },
           success: function(doc) {
                $(doc).each(function() {
                   calendar.addEvent( this );
                })
           }
       }) 
    } 
  })
     calendar.render(); 
});
```

While debugging my javascript I can see the rows of events appear in 'doc'. First I tried to bulk add them to the agenda, but that didn't seem to work. Now I'm adding them one-by-one, buth they still don't appear. I have checked the this variable in the debugger and it shows a single event: 
title:"value", start:"2019-08-01". In fact I'm using the sample list that comes with the package. Can someone point me to the right direction in what I'm doing wrong?

other options I tried (with no luck ;-):
I tried to leave the jquery out, but with similar effect:

```
    success: function(doc) {
            doc.forEach(function(value) {
               calendar.addEvent( value );
            })
       }

    success: function(doc) {
         $(doc).each(function() {
            calendar.addEvent({
                  title:this.title,
                  start:this.start
               });
       })
```

Not sure if it's helpful, but I added the selectable option and tested the select  option. The calendar.addevent on the select: doesn't add the event either. Since this is copied from the sample i'm quite confused now. Fun part is that if you replace the ajax part with a regular [] expression that all works well. Even the selectable options, so there's definitely something wrong with my ajax implementation, in regards to this component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the DOCS you need to have a `successCallback` that will return the events to the calendar.

> Here is the docs https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function
>
> Here is a simple Demo https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/gOOJrWV?editors=0010

And in short, I can say that you need to set the events like this.

```
events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
      successCallback([
        {"resourceId":"a","title":"event 1","start":"2019-11-23","end":"2019-11-25"},
        {"resourceId":"b","title":"event 3","start":"2019-11-24T12:00","end":"2019-11-25T06:00"},
        {"resourceId":"b","title":"event 4","start":"2019-11-24T07:30","end":"2019-11-24T09:30"},
        {"resourceId":"b","title":"event 5","start":"2019-11-24T10:00","end":"2019-11-24T15:00"},
        {"resourceId":"a","title":"event 2","start":"2019-11-24T09:00","end":"2019-11-24T14:00"}
      ])
    }
```

you didn't mention the events data that comes from Ajax request, so I can say you need to provide the data like what said on docs.

---

**Addition**

**Note: Event's date are on 11/28 and 11,29 so navigate to those dates to see the events.**

> Demo https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/qBBGVbG?editors=0010

```
events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    var arrevents = [];
    jQuery.get( "https://api.myjson.com/bins/16ubhe", function( data ) {
      
      // var response = JSON.parse(data);
      // $.each(response, function(k, v) {
      //     arrevents.push(v);
      // });
      arrevents = data;
      successCallback(arrevents);
    });
},
```

Comment: I did check this page out originally and have applied the success callback function with no positive result. I have been trying a lot. The issue is that if I supply a regular url to retrieve the events that it works well, but if I change it to ajax it does not, while the parameters seems to be ok, at least if I look into the Chromium debugger. In fact, even the onclickevent is not working if I use the ajax approach.So actually I think the problem lies in how to convert the data received from ajax in the object array into the strings needed to add the events... (return info did not do the job)

Comment: actually i didn't try events: function(...) { successCallback(info); } will try that asap.

Comment: @aidee so, if you have problem with ajax process here I have an answer and sample as well added to this answer, check it may help you better.https://stackoverflow.com/a/59025640/9246297